# No operator used with SQL 'WHERE' clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I've inherited a legacy product using MS Access and came across the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT StudyNumber FROM Studies WHERE ToBeArchived
```

The `ToBeArchived` column has a data type of `BIT` (ODBC) or `Boolean` (OleDB) and the query appears to work, in the sense that only those records where `ToBeArchived` is `True` (or `1`) are returned. This appears to be similar to the C++ statement `if (myBool) ...` rather than the more verbose `if (myBool == true) ...`.

I've searched a variety of SQL tutorials (such as [wsschools](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_where.asp)) and cannot find any examples with `WHERE` used without an operator such as `=`, `>`, `LIKE` and so on. To me, the SQL should be either:

```
SELECT StudyNumber FROM Studies WHERE ToBeArchived = 1
```

or

```
SELECT StudyNumber FROM Studies WHERE ToBeArchived = True
```

Is using `WHERE` without an operator "standard" SQL? Could it be specific to MS Access and the JET database engine?

Comment: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.

That is the error raised in standard MSSQL. The Access engine must be handling it in such a way that it applies the value at run time.

Comment: It is "standard" SQL if the type is `boolean` -- and `bit` is not boolean.  But it is not uncommon for databases to support some version of this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: OK, thanks Gordon. ODBC's `BIT` is the same as OleDB's `Boolean` isn't it? When I extract the database schema from the table using ODBC, I get "BIT", and when I repeat that with OleDB, I get "Boolean".

Comment: What's "standard"  SQL? Are you referring to a certain ANSI standard? If so, just read it.

Comment: T-SQL does NOT have a Boolean column type. You can't declare a Boolean type in code, but EXPRESISONS do in fact return a true/false expression type!!! Access can do this because you can declare a Boolean column type. And in fact most odbc drivers to SQL server cast/convert the bit (integer) type to Boolean on the other end. Access has a native true/false type for columns - SQL server does not - and even cast(column as "type") does not support a Boolean datatype. But a lot of databases will support that syntax - and often the sql can/will auto-cast. sqlite for example supports that syntax

Comment: FYI, if it's not already clear, Access's SQL *is* different than T-SQL, and others, sometimes quite different. If you're going to be working with it much, there's a good, older reference book by Bagui et al. Another difference to be aware of, in Access, Yes/True is **-1**, not 1.